# How can I speed up/replace my double for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization

This is my code for iterating on "**ListOfDocuments**" which is a list of over **500,000** dicts. Each of those dicts have around 30 key-value pairs that I need.

```
    for document in ListOfDocuments:
        for field in document:
            if(field=="USELESS"):
                continue
            ExtraList[AllParameters[field]] = document[field]
        ExtraList[AllParameters["C_Name"]] = filename.split(".")[0]
        AppendingDataframe.loc[len(AppendingDataframe)] = ExtraList
```

What I'm trying to do is, store all possible column names in **AllParameters**, loop through the ListOfDocuments followed by looping through the obtained dict, followed by iterating each key-value pair and saving them in **ExtraList** which I append finally in the **AppendingDataframe.**

This approach is extremely slow even on most powerful of the machines and I know this is not the right way to do it. Any help would be very appreciated.

**Edit:**
A sample document looks like a normal key-value with over 30 keys.

Eg

{' FKey':12,'Skey':22,'NConfig':'NA','SCHEMA':'CD123...}

And I'd like to extract and store the individual key-value pairs.

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output data?

Comment: Added the sample.

Comment: ` extract and store the individual key-value pairs` - you mean create separate variable for key-value pair?

Comment: Does just `df = pd.DataFrame(ListOfDocuments)` work here?

Comment: Alderven - I'm planning to perform some operations on them and then store them in a file, probably in CSV format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make threads. You can find out how many files you need to look through and possibly split it across 4 threads. This will make the process much faster as it will allow the documents to be read at the same time

You could start by making a method that accepts a list of files then loop through those. Then you could pass a few sections of the main list to the method and run them in threads. That should provide a decent increase in speed

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by implementing a function that processes a single entry of the list and then use multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as multi
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()

data = manager.list([])

def func(a):          #Implement here the function 
    data.append(a)    #that processes one dict from the list

p = multi.Pool(processes=16)
p.map(func, ListOfDocuments)

print data
```